# jQuery showing comment box

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to learn some jQuery to add to a website I am creating. When the user clicks the "Add Comment" link a text area and post comment button appears but I can't seem to get it to work..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $("#addcomment").click(function () {
            $("#postComment").show("slow");
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="addcomment">
    <a href='#' id="addcomment" class="addcomment">add comment</a>
    </div>
    <div id="postComment" class="postComment">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS

```
#postComment{
display: none;
```

I have tried it on http://jsfiddle.net/2dA3p/2/ without issue but when running in with netbeans I have no luck. I hopefully there is a simple fix or something stupid I am doing.

PS this is my first post so hopefully I have followed the rules correctly :S

Thanks

Comment: ___ID must be unique___

Comment: Afaik jsfiddle uses ready event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register your handler after the element already exists, so it must be wrapped in a DOM ready handler. In jQuery, the syntax for this is to wrap the code in `$(function() {});`

Additionally, the element IDs must be unique, or it's undefined which one the handler will actually be bound to (usually it's the first in the DOM tree that jQuery encounters).

If the event needs to be bound to multiple elements, use the class attribute instead of the ID attribute, then use a class selector.

```
$(function () {
    $("#addcomment").click(function () {
        $("#postComment").show("slow");
    });
});
```

Possible markup (minus the superfluous classes, but you can re-add them if you need to, no harm):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="addcomment"> <a href='#'>add comment</a></div>
        <div id='postComment'>
            <textarea name='comment' id='comment'></textarea>
            <input type='submit' value='Post Comment' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/2dA3p/4/)

Answer (score 1):

So. you need to either put your javascript after the elements you are interacting with or put that code inside a DOM ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addcomment").click(function () {
        $("#postComment").show("slow");
    });
});
```